# Pandas last is returning more data than it should. Is this pandas or me?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using last to filter date data. However, it seems to not be working. The either timeframe ie 7D and I believe 14D return more data than they should. 7D for CAT should return no data. I also tried with 1W with the same result. Am I doing something wrong or is pandas?

The method to gather the data is below.

```
# Gets the openinsider information for insider trading of stocks
def get_openinsider_stock_activity(stocks):
    # Format search string from stocks
    # URL gets 500 entries only
    stocks = stocks.upper().replace(' ', '+')  # format the tickers to be lis
    print('Search String: ', stocks)
    url = f'http://openinsider.com/screener?s={stocks}&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=1461&fdr=&td=0&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=0&nfl=&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=300&page=1'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    try:
        rows = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tinytable'}).find('tbody').findAll('tr')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error! Skipping")
        print(f"This URL was not successful: {url}")
        print(e)
        return

    # Get headers first
    header_row = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tinytable'}).find('thead').findAll('tr')
    headers = []
    for row in header_row:
        for col in row:
            for header in col:
                text = col.text.strip()
                if text == '':
                    continue
                headers.append(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text))

    body_rows = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tinytable'}).find('tbody').findAll('tr')
    # Iterate over rows of table
    insider_data = []
    for row in body_rows:
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        if not cols:
            continue
        for cell in cols:
            cell_value = cell.find('a').text.strip() if cell.find('a') else cell.text.strip()
        body = {key: cols[index].find('a').text.strip() if cols[index].find('a') else cols[index].text.strip()
                for index, key in enumerate(headers)}
        insider_data.append(body)
    insider_data = pd.DataFrame(insider_data)
    return insider_data
```

The method that filters the data using .last() is below

```
    data = []
    for stock in ['AAPL', 'BA', 'GME', 'XOM', 'CAT']:
        data.append(get_openinsider_stock_activity(stock))
    data = pd.concat(data)

    for timeframe in ['7D', '14D', '1M']:

        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

        count_data = data.copy()
        count_data['Trade Date'] = pd.to_datetime(count_data['Trade Date'])
        # HERE
        count_data = count_data.sort_values(by='Trade Date', ascending=True).set_index('Trade Date').last(timeframe)
        print(count_data)
```

if we check CAT [here](http://openinsider.com/screener?s=CAT&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=7&fdr=&td=0&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=0&nfl=&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1) we can set that there were no buyers for 1 week prior as no table shows up. However, my code shows there was one seller but that record should only be in 2 weeks ago.

Comment: It's never pandas

Comment: @Chris it works fine for the higher timeframes and I manually checked the lower timeframes data. It is not properly filtering them and is it just the `last` method call.

Comment: confirming, is it just the 1 week that seems to be failing. '1W' and '7D' both return more than one week's worth of data.

Comment: It may be difficult for people to try to help you because of all the extra code.  Perhaps you could change your question to post just a sample of the data and the minimum code required to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Chris updated with simplified code.

Comment: @DavidFrick could it be the day week starts with is different from pandas in CAT ?

Comment: so it appears all the timeframes return more data than they should. XOM last('3M') returns a value more than 3 months ago, BUT it was 3 months ago ie it was 5-01-2023 so it was in the last three months ie May is 5, August is 8, but by days it was more than 3 months ago. Not sure why the day filters ie 7D and 14D do not work. I am stumped at how to fix this. How do I give pandas a datetime to filter on not using last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html), at the very end it makes a point to note exactly the behavior that is tripping you up.

> Notice the data for 3 last calendar days were returned, not the last 3
> observed days in the dataset, and therefore data for 2018-04-11 was
> not returned.

You can see it in the example:

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='2D')
ts = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=i)
ts.last('3D')
```

Output

```
            A
2018-04-13  3
2018-04-15  4
```

What you may be looking for is a relative date offset, like n days prior to today:

```
ts.loc[ts.index >= (pd.to_datetime('today')-pd.Timedelta(days=7))]
```

Returns an empty dataframe becuase there are no records within the last 3 calendar days and:

```
ts.loc[ts.index >= (pd.to_datetime('today')-pd.Timedelta(days=1938))]
```

returns only two records as expected

Comment: You know, I had referenced the documentation multiple times, and each time I read it backwards. the last observed records.  ie  Cheers